Make Button on simulation controls change a Select output condition from true to false
I'm new to Analogic and I'm having trouble trying to make a button on my Simulation Controls page change the value of a Select Output condition from true to false (parametroCobroSeccion == true). I can't find a solution on how to do it; I'm not very familiar with coding, so I can't figure it out.
I try setting up the button, but cant understand how to make the change I want.

In the button action you do:
parametroCobroSeccion=!parametroCobroSeccion;

This will toggle the value of the variable to the opposite value it currently has.
If you just want the button to change it to false:
parametroCobroSeccion=false;

